# Как получить индекс элемента ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

Я хочу получить индекс выделенного в текущий момент элемента ListBox. Но код `MessageBox.Show(listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString());` все время выдает **1**. Всего элементов внутри ListBox **3**. При нажатии на первый программа выдает окно с сообщением **1**. При клике по остальным двум ничего не происходит.

А следующий код выдает **1** при запуске программы и **1** при каждом клике на первый элемент. На остальные два вообще не реагирует.

```
private void ListBoxItem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("1");
}

private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("2");
}
```

Как получать индект всех выделенных элементов?
Какое событие для этого нужно перехватывать?

**Добавил XAML:**

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="125,0,0,0">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="Processor speed:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
            <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" Height="76" Margin="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="108" MouseDown="listBox1_MouseDown">
                <ListBoxItem Content="Economy mode" FontSize="11" IsSelected="True" Selected="ListBoxItem_Selected"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Standard mode" FontSize="11" IsSelected="True"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Fast mode" FontSize="11"/>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

**Правка 2:**

Через `SelectedItem` тоже пробовал:

```
private void ListBoxItem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

Но здесь выдает `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Покажите XAML...

Comment: Пишете на WPF? Тогда зачем вам `SelectedIndex`? Могу поспорить, _на самом деле_ вам нужен `SelectedItem`.

Comment: Вам надо ловить `listbox.SelectionChanged`. На время прихода `item.Selected` выделение ещё не «провалилось» в `ListBox`. (И проверяйте на `null`, вот и не будет `NullReferenceException`.)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь получилось

Comment: @VladD, может, оформите ответ, чтобы закрыть вопрос?

Comment: @Vlad: Угу, так и сделал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам стоит ловить `listbox.SelectionChanged`. На время прихода `item.Selected` выделение ещё не «провалилось» в `ListBox`, так что спрашивать на этот момент у `ListBox` ещё рано.

(А `NullReferenceException` взялось потому, что в начале `SelectedItem` есть `null`.)